# Error: ControllerController could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

i just created a controller like this:

```
<?php
class UsuarioController extends AppController {

}
?>
```

I went to http://urubu.zz.mu/controller/UsuarioController.php to test, and this was the result:

Error: ControllerController could not be found.

Error: Create the class ControllerController below in file: app/Controller/ControllerController.php

}

Theres no class ControllerController in my project.
I found a line in AppController(From CakePHP) :

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

But i dont know what it means and how to solve it.

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Go to **http : //your-local-url/usuario** and you should find the controller (no need to put "controller" in the url). You need to read the docs, controller is in plural (so "UsuariosController"), and the urls are clearly explained there.

Comment: I recommend the tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Read the wealth of documentation in the [Online CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) to better understand CakePHP.

---

**Accessing a Controller's `index()` action**

In CakePHP, you access the `index` action of your Controller via the URL like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/usarios
```

You do NOT need to add "controller" to the URL.

The above would run the `index()` action within the `UsariosController`.

---

**Accessing another action within a Controller**

```
http://www.mydomain.com/usarios/register
```

This would run the `register()` action within the `UsariosController`.

---

**Passing variables to actions within a Controller**

```
http://www.mydomain.com/usarios/view/1
```

This would pass `1` to the `register($userId) {` action in your `UsariosController`.

Comment: @LucasRodrigues - You can mark it as the answer though - if it answers your question.